# How to integrate typescript project with html

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to call a typescript function from the HTML body. However, I am unable to call my function(D2O_main()) from HTML as I don't fully understand the generated js code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I generated the js using the following command:
tsc --module umd main.ts

Here's the html file.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="D2O_main();">
    <canvas id="canvas-001"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the main.ts file:

```
import {Init} from "./Core/IO/Init"
let init:Init;
function D2O_main() {
    init = new Init("canvas-001");
}
```

Here's the generated main.js file:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "./Core/IO/Init"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    var Init_1 = require("./Core/IO/Init");
    var init;
    function D2O_main() {
        init = new Init_1.Init("canvas-001");
    }
});
```

I'm getting the following error at the browser console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: D2O_main is not defined
    at onload

Once again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's because nested functions are function-scoped - you'd need to move `function D20_main` outside of the IIFE it is contained in, effectively making it a globally accessible function:

```
(function (factory) {...})(function (require, exports) {...}); 
function D20_main() {...}
```

Comment: I do not want to change the js file manually since it is autogenerated. Please suggest a modification to the .ts file or .html file.